# buildozer debug error "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" error

Tags: kivy, apk, buildozer

I get this error when i run "buildozer android debug" it's same thing about jave !!
I'm not sure ; any way after i run the command i get :

And this's all the commands that i run on the terminal and i think that is relate to this problem

```
$ apt-get update

$ apt-get install default-jdk

enter code here$ wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip
$unzip sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip
$ export PATH=/opt/pradip/tools:/opt/pradip/tools/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/bin
```

And the following is the error that i get when i run "buildozer android debug"

```
root@kivy-VirtualBox:/home/kivy/Desktop# buildozer android debug

# Check configuration tokens

Buildozer is running as root!

This is not recommended, and may lead to problems later.

Are you sure you want to continue [y/n]? y


# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian `dpkg' package management program version 1.17.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' 
\'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' 
\'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517\' \'pytoml\' \'virtualenv\''
# Cwd None
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. 
Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that 
date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More 
details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at 
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
# Apache ANT found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Android NDK found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c
# Installing/updating SDK platform tools if necessary
# Run '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager 
tools platform-tools'
# Cwd /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli : Unsupported major.minor
version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
# Command failed: /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android- 
sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

please if the above command are the reason for the error tell how to fix it and if not
please tell me how to fix in details in simple way because
 i try to look in the internet and i found nothing
thanks
note : I'm using buildozer on VirtualBox

Comment: Make sure you have openjdk 8 installed.

Comment: i try and not work it may be some thing else

Comment: not work it's give this error                                                                      
 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk

Comment: That is a java class file version mismatch. Likely you are trying to execute a java 8 file using a java runtime that is older than java 8.

Comment: sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk .. solve the error  thank you every one